# What is the default type of request body in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

what is the default type of @Requestbody in Spring boot if i dont send anything (json or xml) and will it accept?.

Comment: `java.lang.Object`

Answer (score 0):

> Whether body content is required. Default is true, leading to an
>   exception thrown in case there is no body content. Switch this to
>   false if you prefer null to be passed when the body content is null.

[RequestBody springframework javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestBody.html)

Comment: Hey itpr, If I send the Body content and I didn't mention whether Json or XML while sending the body contents. When will it accept it?

Comment: Did you try `@RequestBody(required=false)`

Comment: Hey itpr, lets say i am calling rest controller from ajax, i have sent the request body in ajax but i didn't send content type.will the controller accepts the request from ajax or it will throw some exception?